# Selenium chrome driver click() method not always clicking on elements

Tags: c#, selenium, integration-testing

I am writing integration tests in c# and when I use the click() method on certain elements inside a dialog box nothing happens and I get no errors. It will click some of the elements inside the dialog but not others. I thought if it wasn't selecting them properly then it would throw and exception but it runs smooth and says test passed even though it never actually clicked the button. The dialog box is an iframe.

I thought maybe it was trying to click a button that wasn't display yet or enabled so I added this before the click() call:

```
 _driver.SwitchTo().Frame(_frameElement);
     _wait.Until(d =>
    {
      var shippingInfoButton = d.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[title ='Info']"));
      return shippingInfoButton.Displayed && shippingInfoButton.Enabled;
    });
       var infoButton = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[title ='Info']"));
        ScrollToElement(infoButton);
        infoButton.Click();
```

again this runs with no thrown exceptions so I'm assuming it has found the element and it is both displayed and enabled.

Let me know if you need any more info. Thanks

Comment: where are you clicking? From what I see you are only finding the element?

Comment: right below that line of code.

Comment: I see you updated your question.

Comment: Yes, i use the same code block to click a cancel button in the same _frameElement and it works fine, can't figure out why it would click it and not this one.

Comment: I found a temporary solution by using a javascript click method intead of the selenium chrome drivers .click(), if any of you know why this works and the selenium method doesn't i'd love to learn. Thanks. I'll post my solution as an answer when it lets me in a few hours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't explain why the selenium driver .click() method won't fire on some elements in the page but not others, but I did find a solution.

Using IJavaScriptExecutor you can click the element using javascript instead and in my case it worked.

Here is the code to run the IJavaScriptExecutor and below is my whole method.

```
    //IJavaScriptExecutor
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = _driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

         js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", infoButton);

    //my whole method for clicking the button and returning the page object
    public ShippingMethodDetailsPageObject SelectShippingMethodInfo()
    {
        _driver.SwitchTo().Frame(_frameElement);
        _wait.Until(d =>
        {
         var shippingInfoButton = d.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[title='Info']"));
            return shippingInfoButton.Displayed && shippingInfoButton.Enabled;
        });

         var infoButton = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[title ='Info']"));
         IJavaScriptExecutor js = _driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

         js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", infoButton);
        _driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();

        return new ShippingMethodDetailsPageObject(_driver, false);
    }
```

Comment: This is the one which worked for me with latest chrome driver, I tried everything else but still it was not able to click the label element. Thanks a lot. `protected static void ClickUsingJS(IWebElement elem)
        {
            //var infoButton = CurrentDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[title ='Info']"));
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = CurrentDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

            js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", elem);
            CurrentDriver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
        }`    This should be accepted as answer. Cheers!

Comment: this works but it would be important to warn that this is masking potential errors, the native selenium click throws an error if the element is not clickable (a good thing), and this doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar problem.  If it's the same problem there's a fault in the ChromeDriver it can't click certain elements because of surrounding divs etc.  Bit lame really.

A simple fix is to send the Enter key e.g. element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter).  Seems to work across all browsers.

Comment: I'm going to try this! Thanks for the help.

Comment: One thing to note here: if you're  trying to click something that isn't a link or a button etc. then you'll need to add a tabindex to it and listen for the keyup.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? The problem is automating a click on that element and not listening for a click by something else.  Thanks.

Comment: Enter or space key to click does not work for me. Btw, is there any link/github issue for the chrome driver fault that OP mentioned ?

Comment: This worked great! We were having issues with Spectron (which uses WebDriver and ChromeDriver) where the clicks weren't registering after switching windows. Adding a `.keys("Enter")` did the trick. Odd that this issue would pop up almost 7 years later!

Answer (score 0):

I have some tests that works in Firefox all the times, and in Chrome it drove me mad, because sometimes it passed successfully, and sometimes the ".click" didn't work and it would fail the test.

Took a long time to notice it, but the reason was: I used to sometimes minimize the browser to 80% to be able to see the browser along side my IDE. it appears that the ".click" doesn't work when I did it.

At least for me this was the issue