# Karate UI: Unable to click on element when running on remote grid

Tags: javascript, karate

I am trying to click on a button using this command:
`Then submit().click("//input[@id='myButton' and @type='button' and @value='CLICK HERE']")`

This works fine when I set up the driver on my local machine:
`* configure driver = { type: 'chrome', showDriverLog: true}`

However, on the remote machine, it doesn't work.
`* configure driver = { type: 'chromedriver',  start: false, webDriverUrl: 'https://mygrid.com' }`

I've tried multiple things such as:
`And  locate("//input[@id='myButton' and @type='button' and @value='CLICK HERE']").exists` -> This returns true

This does scroll down so the button is visible(I can see from screenshot)
    `And script("//input[@id='myButton' and @type='button' and @value='CLICK HERE']", '_.scrollIntoView()') And click('//input[@id='myButton' and @type='button' and @value='CLICK HERE']')`

The action of clicking on the button doesn't throw an error in Karate, however it doesn't actually get done when on a remote driver..

Comment: there can be subtle browser differences. this needs research which perhaps only you are in a position to do. if you can replicate this following this process, then something can be done: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 0):

For that step try using a `mouse('locator').click()` operation.

Comment: That doesn't work

Comment: @DevOpsUj help us replicate the problem

Comment: I'm not sure how but I did find that chromedriver can sometimes cause issues when clicking on element. Is it possible to replicate the following code using karate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112363/selenium-chrome-driver-click-method-not-always-clicking-on-elements

Comment: @DevOpsUj just took a quick look. if you mean how to execute JS in a page, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60800181/143475